# ST_Length (GEOM, true) for calculating distances in Geographic Reference System

Tags: coordinate-system, postgis-2.0, length

I use (1) ST_Length (ST_Transform (geom, 3395)) to get distances in meters from points in Geographic Reference Systems EPSG: 4326. The thing is I found that  with  (2) ST_Length (geom, true)  you can get also the distance in meters but using the spheroid.

If I am right, is the option (2) more accurate if the GIS project use a Geographic Reference System for Global data, especially near to the poles?

ST_Length reference: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Length.html

EPSG:3395 reference: https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3395/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can if your data is stored in a geography column, or cast from geometry to geography.  If you run ST_Length against geometry it will return the units the data is stored in (feet, meters, degrees), if you run ST_Length against geography it will return the answer in meters.

See this [workshop](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/geography.html) for details on the difference.

Comment: In my opinion, HeyOverThere's answer is more precise that mkennedy's one. And also it makes me notice that I was using the wrong data type for working with Global Data, I should use "geography" type instead of  "geometry".

Anyway thanks to both of you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

EPSG:3395 uses the Mercator projection. Mercator is not designed for distance calculations, instead it preserves shapes/angles, so yes, option 2, will give more accurate distances.

Comment: This answer is also correct because doing ST_Length (geom, true) is equivalent to cast from geometry to geography like doing ST_Length (geom::geography)